# How to use SwitchUserListener in Symfony2?

Tags: php, symfony

I'm trying to do a redirect when a user impersonates another user.

For this I registered a service:

```
ACME_listener.security_switch_user:
    class: ACME\CustomerLoginBundle\Listener\SecuritySwitchUserListener
    arguments:  [@service_container, @router, @security.context]
    tags:
        - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: security.switch_user, method: onSecuritySwitchUser }
```

My listener class looks like this:

```php
namespace ACME\CustomerLoginBundle\Listener;

use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Event\SwitchUserEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseEvent;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Firewall\ListenerInterface;

class SecuritySwitchUserListener implements ListenerInterface {
    public function __construct($appContainer, $router) {
        $this->router = $router;
        $this->appContainer = $appContainer;
    }

    public function onSecuritySwitchUser(SwitchUserEvent $event) {
       echo "im in here!";
      // this does get called

    }

    public function handle(GetResponseEvent $event) {
        echo "but not here :(";
        // this does not get called!
    }

}
```

Now the problem is that I can not redirect the user from within the `onSecuritySwitchUser` method. Returning a `RedirectResponse` does NOT work and the `SwitchUserEvent` does NOT have a `setResponse()` method.

What do I have to do so that the `handle()` method does get called?

Answer (score 0):

I think that `handle()` is called from `onSecuritySwitchUser()`. But I can be wrong.

**UPDATE**

You can overwrite the event with your own request :)

Look at:

```
Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Firewall\SwitchUserListener
```

And then Dispach new SwitchUserEvent with overwritten request

```
if (null !== $this->dispatcher) {
        $switchEvent = new SwitchUserEvent($request, $token->getUser());
        $this->dispatcher->dispatch(SecurityEvents::SWITCH_USER, $switchEvent);
}
```

Maybe that will help you.

Comment: No, onSecuritySwitchUser() is purely defined by me. It does not call handle() and calling handle() manually from it would not help.